# The redirect_uri issue in LinkedIn Login using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add LinkedIn authentication with React following this link **https://github.com/orionsoft/react-linkedin-login**. The tutorial doesn't mention the `redirect_uri` due to which I have left it as blank. But when I try to log in using my react app, an error occurs What is the correct `redirect_uri` to use in react application. The LinkedIn error goes like this **"The `redirect_uri` does not match the registered value"**.

My website URL is **http://localhost:3000**

Please refer the screenshots for the settings of LinkedIn Developer Console [image]

I am adding the code in react

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LinkedIn from 'react-linkedin-login'

class SocialLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }
  
  callbackLinkedIn ({code, redirectUri}) {
    console.log(code+"linked in code")
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-box">
        <div className="social-login">
             <LinkedIn
              clientId='***********'
              callback={this.callbackLinkedIn.bind(this)}
              text='LinkedIn' /> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SocialLogin;
```

I am getting this issue "**"The redirect_uri does not match the registered value"**".please refer the last image [image]

I have given the 4 redirect URLs like:

1. http://localhost:3000
2. http://localhost:3000/callback
3. http://localhost:3000/signin-linkedin
4. http://localhost:3000/auth/linkedin/callback

But I am getting the same issue. Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the redirectUri is given to you. Can you do a console log of  code and redirectUri inside `callbackLinkedIn` to see what it comes with?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply@Rodius,there is nothing to display in console

Comment: I think it's not working with localhost. You could test it with a free hosting demo account.

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: @AlluManikyam, The issue could be because of `http://localhost:3000`, while the return url is coming as `http://localhost:3000/`. So try adding the trailing slash as well in your return url list

Comment: can you share your project on github or the package.json of your project here. The library you are using, is an old one and is not compatible with latest React. It also uses the oauth legacy api of Linkedin.

Comment: What you use in backend code ?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing your redirect URL in the screenshot, it can be deciphered that:
`redirect_uri = http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F` 
which translates to `http://localhost:3000/`.

You are missing a `/` in the end. Your currently added URLs are all unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **"http://localhost:3000/"** in Authorized URI section. The request sent to Linkedin with the trailing slash at the end  as parameter for redirect_uri.

I have attached the screenshots below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue might be the fact that the initial URL(The URL making the API Call) and the redirect URL(The URL which should open post response from linkedin) probably have different domains.

You can use a tool like filder to capture the API call to linkedIn login API and check what was the url in HTTP Request. You need to put a url with the same domain in the RedirectURL.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you passing the same clientId value as in developers console also while going through both the snaps you provided the clientId is not matching.

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=**81jbduxh1ev9tj**&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile

Answer (score 0):

A lot of API's don't trust `localhost`. I'd suggest trying some tools like https://ngrok.com which tunnels your http/https traffic and gives you unique url.